# How to repair winform element's function call if it is deleted?

Tags: c#

I am building application in .Net C#. 
I accidentally double clicked the textbox in my application, and there is a textbox_click function being created, I deleted that function because I dont need it but when I run my application there was a :

```
Error   1   'Bond_Yield_Calculator.BaseForm' does not contain a definition for 'textBox5_TextChanged' and no extension method 'textBox5_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Bond_Yield_Calculator.BaseForm' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Alex Chan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Bond Yield Calculator\Bond Yield Calculator\BaseForm.Designer.cs   139 77  Bond Yield Calculator
```

error, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double-click on the error and it will jump you to that location in code.  Delete the line of code that created the event handler.

If this is winforms, it will look something like

```
Bond_Yield_Calculator.BaseForm.TextBoxChanged += new EventHandler(textBox5_TextChanged);
```

It'll probably be in a file named

> *xxxxx*.designer.cs  (Where *xxxxxx* is the name of a form or control in your project.)

Alternatively, if it's ASP.NET you will see inside the tag something that looks like

> OnTextChanged="textBox5_TextChanged"

Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

The method should have the following signature:

```
protected void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

See the [definition on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the event handler in the code behind does not remove the event completely.  You'll have to remove it from the designer.

Open up the properties window in Visual Studio (`CTRL+W,P`).
Click the textbox in the designer (only once!), then click the lightning bolt button in the properties window.  Find the text changed event listed, and delete the text in the box.